# How to force Linq 2 SQL to use EXEC instead of EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

We are executing stored procedures using L2S and during trace analysis we noticed that LINQ uses SP_EXECUTESQL instead of EXEC.

I do understand that there are advantages of using SP_EXECUTESQL, but we are in the process of troubleshooting a mysterious DB issue and I was wondering if it's possible to force LINQ use EXEC instead of EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL?

Thanks

Comment: "we are in the process of troubleshooting a mysterious DB issue" - what is it and why do you think calling 'EXEC' instead of 'sp_executesql' will help you?

Comment: agree with @Mitch Wheat. the only difference between the two is really performance (executesql promotes better queryplan re-use). so unless your "mysterious DB issue" is really "performance issues", i dont see why you care about this.

Comment: Yes it's a perf issue. The legacy app that we are replacing (which uses raw ADO .NET types) runs smoothly, it's only when the same procedures are called using L2S that it slows down a lot sometimes and the only difference we found out in the trace files was this statement. I guess there's something wrong with the way transactions are happening, but i just wanted to discount SP_EXECUTESQL as a possible reason.